# Simulate keypresses but only to specific window?

Tags: delphi

There are lots of examples of how to use the Windows API to simulate pressing of keys. One option would be something like the code below.

However what i'm trying to achieve is one step further. The code below requires the app you want to send the keys, to be always the foreground window. I'm trying to sending keys to a window that is NOT in focus, so i can automate tasks / macros with this window minimized.

Is there any alternative ?

Thanks

```
procedure PostKeyEx32(key: Word; const shift: TShiftState;
  specialkey: Boolean);
type
    TShiftKeyInfo = record
      shift: Byte ;
      vkey: Byte ;
    end;
    ByteSet = set of 0..7 ;
 const
    shiftkeys: array [1..3] of TShiftKeyInfo =
      ((shift: Ord(ssCtrl) ; vkey: VK_CONTROL),
      (shift: Ord(ssShift) ; vkey: VK_SHIFT),
      (shift: Ord(ssAlt) ; vkey: VK_MENU)) ;
 var
    flag: DWORD;
    bShift: ByteSet absolute shift;
    j: Integer;
 begin
    for j := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      if shiftkeys[j].shift in bShift then
        keybd_event(shiftkeys[j].vkey, MapVirtualKey(shiftkeys[j].vkey, 0), 0, 0) ;
    end;
    if specialkey then
      flag := KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY
    else
      flag := 0;

    if key = 47 then
      begin
      keybd_event(VkKeyScan('/'), 1, 0, 0);
      end
      else
      begin
      keybd_event(key, MapvirtualKey(key, 0), flag, 0) ;
      flag := flag or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
      keybd_event(key, MapvirtualKey(key, 0), flag, 0) ;
      end;

    for j := 3 downto 1 do
    begin
      if shiftkeys[j].shift in bShift then
        keybd_event(shiftkeys[j].vkey, MapVirtualKey(shiftkeys[j].vkey, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) ;
    end;
 end;
```

Comment: If you want to send key presses to certain window then you should use `Send message` to send proper WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages to that window. I don't have any working example for sending key presses but I can share similar code for sending mouse clicks if you wish

Comment: @SilverWarior Please share this example, maybe i can adapt it to send keystrokes instead...

Comment: First, `keybd_event()` is old and deprecated, use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead. Second, [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513), use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) instead.

Comment: @Silver No, that's not how you fake input.

Comment: @delphirules UI Automation is the platform automation library.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't UI automation requires that the application whose UI are you automating is specifically designed for this?

Comment: @SilverWarior most UIs use standard UI controls provided by the OS. They support UI Automation out of the box. It is only UI custom controls you would have to worry about, in which case, yes, authors would have to provide appropriate support for UI Automation

Comment: @RemyLebeau So if the application that OP is trying to automate relies on using of standard UI controls then the right approach would be using UI automation. But what if the application OP is trying automate does not rely on standard UI controls? Then I'm guessing using `SendMessage` might be viable option. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @SilverWarior you would have to ask the UI author. SendMessage may or may not work (think of windowless controls, for instance)

Comment: `sendMessage( form.handle, WM_KEYDOWN, ... )` always send to the form. In this form you have to declare a Win Message Handler method. `procedure onKeyDown( var message : TMessage ); message = WM_KEYDOWN;`

Comment: @User007 can you provide a working example ?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example to send/handle WM_KEYUP messages by a specific window. But it is the same for any other message types (custom ones as well, just the params depends on its type)
The destination window have to implement the message handler procedure.

```
procedure onKeyPressed( var message_ : TWMKeyUp ); message WM_KEYUP;
```

To send the messages, you have to use `sendMessage` with the right parameters.
The first parameter is the handle of the window, the second one is the message ID, the 3rd and 4th ones depends on the message type defined by the message ID.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure onKeyPressed( var message_ : TWMKeyUp ); message WM_KEYUP;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ( edit1.text <> '' ) then
    sendMessage( handle, WM_KEYUP, cardinal( edit1.text[1] ), 0 );
end;

procedure TForm1.onKeyPressed( var message_ : TWMKeyUp );
var
  c : char;
begin
  c := char( message_.CharCode );
  label1.caption := label1.caption + c;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

For most apps WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP will be enough:
http://www.delphigroups.info/2/80/324746.html

But for some apps you will require [API hooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FZGAs3rlAw) on [functions like GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645530%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) plus a way to load your dll into a target process: https://progamercity.net/delphi/647-delphi-dll-injection-functions.html. All that will be very suspicious from Antivirus software point of view.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The 'hWindow: HWnd' parameter should be my application handle or the form handle ?

Comment: hWindow is target window, that should recieve key press message. You can get if from [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) or other WinAPI functions.